# easy inequality to prove

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\log_2(x)+\frac{1-x}{x} > 0$

I think the answer is easy but I've no clue how to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

Take the exponents of both sides, it is equivalent to showing $xe^{\frac{1}{x}-1} > 1$. But $e^x = 1+x+\cdots > 1+x$ whenever $x$ is positive, and thus $xe^{\frac{1}{x}-1} > x(1+\frac{1}{x}-1) = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\log x+\frac{1-x}{x} > 0
\iff \log x+\frac{1}{x} - 1> 0
\iff \frac{1}{x} -1 >  \log \frac 1x
$$
follows from
$$
\frac 1{1+t}< 1\implies \log(1+u) = \int_0^u \frac{dt}{1+t} < u
$$when $u>0.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = x\ln x + 1 - x$, then $f'(x) = \ln x + 1 - 1 = \ln x < 0$ since $x < 1$. So $f$ decreases, and $f(x) > f(1) = 0$, so $$x\ln x + 1 - x > 0\implies \ln x + \frac{1 - x}x > 0.$$

Comment: your method works the most simply but thanks very much everyone for answering